# access statement convert to Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

how can I convert to T-Sql this one?

```
IIf([ESSValue]<>0,Int([ESSValue]*100),"")
```

Comment: If/else logic in sql is normally done with the `case when` keywords.

Comment: This is TSQL. If you are doing operation on integers, you can't return string value. Try null instead.

Comment: What type is `[ESSValue]` ?? Why you convert it to integer?? Why default is "" ... In Sql you cant return two different types for the same field

Comment: [ESSValue] float type

Answer (score 1):

I think the following pretty much does what you want:

```
select coalesce(cast(EssValue * 100 as int), 0)
```

Here is the thinking.  The comparison to zero is unimportant, because 0 times any value is going to be zero.  The `iif()` returns an integer (I think) because the "then" argument is an integer; the empty string gets converted to zero.

I'm not 100% certain about the last statements with regard to MS Access, but that is how `iif()` works in SQL Server.

I should add.  Although I don't approve of `iif()` for conditional expressions (because `case` is the standard and more powerful), SQL Server does support it.  So you could write:

```
IIf([ESSValue]<>0, cast([ESSValue]*100 as int), '')
```

Note:  As I mentioned earlier, the `''` will be converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN ESSValue <> 0 
     THEN CAST(ESSValue * 100 AS INT)
     ELSE NULL
END as fieldname
```

For case expression the default is `NULL` if doesn't meet any condition, so you dont really need the `ELSE` condition

Comment: The original statement never returns `NULL`.